# Perfomance issues with large number of elements in Mithril.js

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

My app has a sort- and filterable list and a few inputs and checkboxes so far.
The problem appears if the list has more than 500 items, then every every element with user input (checkboxes, input fields, menus) start to have a lag around half a second increasing with the number of items in the list. The sorting and filtering of the list is done fast enough but the lag on the input elements is too long.

The question is: how can the list and the input elements be decoupled?

Here is the list code:

```
var list = {}
list.controller = function(args) {
    var model = args.model;
    var vm = args.vm;
    var vmc = args.vmc;
    var appCtrl = args.appCtrl;

    this.items = vm.filteredList;
    this.onContextMenu = vmc.onContextMenu;

    this.isSelected = function(guid) {
        return utils.getState(vm.listState, guid, "isSelected");
    }
    this.setSelected = function(guid) {
        utils.setState(vm.listState, guid, "isSelected", true);
    }
    this.toggleSelected = function(guid) {
        utils.toggleState(vm.listState, guid, "isSelected");
    }
    this.selectAll = function() {
        utils.setStateBatch(vm.listState, "GUID", "isSelected", true, this.items());
    }.bind(this);
    this.deselectAll = function() {
        utils.setStateBatch(vm.listState, "GUID", "isSelected", false, this.items());
    }.bind(this);
    this.invertSelection = function() {
        utils.toggleStateBatch(vm.listState, "GUID", "isSelected", this.items());
    }.bind(this);

    this.id = "201505062224";
    this.contextMenuId = "201505062225";

    this.initRow = function(item, idx) {
        if (item.online) {
            return {
                id : item.guid,
                filePath : (item.FilePath + item.FileName).replace(/\\/g, "\\\\"),
                class : idx % 2 !== 0 ? "online odd" : "online even",
            }
        } else {
            return {
                class : idx % 2 !== 0 ? "odd" : "even"
            }
        }
    };

    // sort helper function
    this.sorts = function(list) {
        return {
            onclick : function(e) {
                var prop = e.target.getAttribute("data-sort-by")
                //console.log("100")
                if (prop) {
                    var first = list[0]
                    if(prop === "selection") {
                        list.sort(function(a, b) { 
                            return this.isSelected(b.GUID) - this.isSelected(a.GUID)
                        }.bind(this)); 
                    } else {
                        list.sort(function(a, b) {
                            return a[prop] > b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : 0
                        })
                    } 
                    if (first === list[0])
                        list.reverse()
                }
            }.bind(this)
        }
    }; 

    // text inside the table can be selected with the mouse and will be stored for
    // later retrieval
    this.getSelected = function() {
        //console.log(utils.getSelText());
        vmc.lastSelectedText(utils.getSelText());
    };
};

list.view = function(ctrl) {

    var contextMenuSelection = m("div", {
        id : ctrl.contextMenuId,
        class : "hide"
    }, [
    m(".menu-item.allow-hover", {
        onclick : ctrl.selectAll
    }, "Select all"),
    m(".menu-item.allow-hover", {
        onclick : ctrl.deselectAll
    }, "Deselect all"), 
    m(".menu-item.allow-hover", {
        onclick : ctrl.invertSelection
    }, "Invert selection") ]);

    var table = m("table", ctrl.sorts(ctrl.items()), [
    m("tr", [
            m("th[data-sort-by=selection]", {
                 oncontextmenu : ctrl.onContextMenu(ctrl.contextMenuId, "context-menu context-menu-bkg", "hide" )
             }, "S"),
            m("th[data-sort-by=FileName]", "Name"),
            m("th[data-sort-by=FileSize]", "Size"), 
            m("th[data-sort-by=FilePath]", "Path"), 
            m("th[data-sort-by=MediumName]", "Media") ]), 
    ctrl.items().map(function(item, idx) {
        return m("tr", ctrl.initRow(item, idx), {
            key : item.GUID
        },
        [ m("td", [m("input[type=checkbox]", {
            id : item.GUID,
            checked : ctrl.isSelected(item.GUID),
            onclick : function(e) {ctrl.toggleSelected(this.id);}
        }) ]),
        m("td", {
            onmouseup: function(e) {ctrl.getSelected();}
            }, item.FileName), 
        m("td", utils.numberWithDots(item.FileSize)), 
        m("td", item.FilePath), 
        m("td", item.MediumName) ])
    }) ])

    return m("div", [contextMenuSelection, table])
}
```

And this is how the list and all other components are initialized from the apps main view:

```
// the main view which assembles all components
var mainCompView = function(ctrl, args) {
    // TODO do we really need him there?
    // add the main controller for this page to the arguments for all
    // added components
    var myArgs = args;
    myArgs.appCtrl = ctrl;

    // create all needed components
    var filterComp = m.component(filter, myArgs);
    var part_filter = m(".row", [ m(".col-md-2", [ filterComp ]) ]);

    var listComp = m.component(list, myArgs);
    var part_list = m(".col-md-10", [ listComp ]);

    var optionsComp = m.component(options, myArgs);
    var part_options = m(".col-md-10", [ optionsComp ]);

    var menuComp = m.component(menu, myArgs);
    var part_menu = m(".menu-0", [ menuComp ]);

    var outputComp = m.component(output, myArgs);
    var part_output = m(".col-md-10", [ outputComp ]);

    var part1 = m("[id='1']", {
        class : 'optionsContainer'
    }, "", [ part_options ]);

    var part2 = m("[id='2']", {
        class : 'menuContainer'
    }, "", [ part_menu ]);

    var part3 = m("[id='3']", {
        class : 'commandContainer'
    }, "", [ part_filter ]);

    var part4 = m("[id='4']", {
        class : 'outputContainer'
    }, "", [ part_output ]);

    var part5 = m("[id='5']", {
        class : 'listContainer'
    }, "", [ part_list ]);

    return [ part1, part2, part3, part4, part5 ];
}

// run
m.mount(document.body, m.component({
    controller : MainCompCtrl,
    view : mainCompView
}, {
    model : modelMain,
    vm : modelMain.getVM(),
    vmc : viewModelCommon
}));
```

I started to workaround the problem by adding m.redraw.strategy("none") and  m.startComputation/endComputation to click events and this solves the problem but is this the right solution? As an example, if I use a Mithril component from a 3rd party together with my list component, how should I do this for the foreign component without changing its code?

On the other side, could my list component use something like the 'retain' flag? So the list doesn't redraw by default unless it's told to do?  But also the problem with a 3rd party component would persist.

I know there are other strategies to solve this problem like pagination for the list but I would like to know what are best practices from the Mithril side.

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Comment: Note that you can always reliably enforce `m.redraw.strategy( 'none' )` in the beat between a redraw trigger (ie Mithril-bound DOM event handler) and the deferred redraw, even if the component triggering the redraw is 3rd party.

Comment: You are right, I can do this for a component as whole. But e.g. I have a filter component that works on a list. It has an input field, a start button and lots if check boxes for filter options. If a check box is clicked, no redraw is necessary, only the start button should trigger one. To accomplish that one could make the redraw strategy configurable through arguments for the component.

Comment: Yes, certainly. What I'm saying is that `m.redraw.strategy` operates for the duration of one global `m. redraw` — it is orthogonal to components. So if a nested (3rd party) component contains checkboxes with redraw events bound to them, you could create a listener in the containing (1st party) component's config to set redraw strategy whenever they were clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Barney I found a solution: Occlusion culling. The original example can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/7JNUy/1/ .
I adapted the code for my needs, especially there was the need to throttle the scroll events fired so the number of redraws are good enough for smooth scrolling. Look at the function obj.onScroll.

```
var list = {}
list.controller = function(args) {
    var obj = {};

    var model = args.model;
    var vm = args.vm;
    var vmc = args.vmc;
    var appCtrl = args.appCtrl;

    obj.vm = vm;
    obj.items = vm.filteredList;
    obj.onContextMenu = vmc.onContextMenu;

    obj.isSelected = function(guid) {
        return utils.getState(vm.listState, guid, "isSelected");
    }
    obj.setSelected = function(guid) {
        utils.setState(vm.listState, guid, "isSelected", true);
    }
    obj.toggleSelected = function(guid) {
        utils.toggleState(vm.listState, guid, "isSelected");
        m.redraw.strategy("none");
    }
    obj.selectAll = function() {
        utils.setStateBatch(vm.listState, "GUID", "isSelected", true, obj.items());
    };
    obj.deselectAll = function() {
        utils.setStateBatch(vm.listState, "GUID", "isSelected", false, obj.items());
    };
    obj.invertSelection = function() {
        utils.toggleStateBatch(vm.listState, "GUID", "isSelected", obj.items());
    };

    obj.id = "201505062224";
    obj.contextMenuId = "201505062225";

    obj.initRow = function(item, idx) {
        if (item.online) {
            return {
                id : item.GUID,
                filePath : (item.FilePath + item.FileName).replace(/\\/g, "\\\\"),
                class : idx % 2 !== 0 ? "online odd" : "online even",
                onclick: console.log(item.GUID)
            }
        } else {
            return {
                id : item.GUID,
                // class : idx % 2 !== 0 ? "odd" : "even",
                onclick: function(e) { obj.selectRow(e, this, item.GUID); 
                    m.redraw.strategy("none");
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // sort helper function
    obj.sorts = function(list) {
        return {
            onclick : function(e) {
                var prop = e.target.getAttribute("data-sort-by")
                // console.log("100")
                if (prop) {
                    var first = list[0]
                    if(prop === "selection") {
                        list.sort(function(a, b) { 
                            return obj.isSelected(b.GUID) - obj.isSelected(a.GUID)
                        }); 
                    } else {
                        list.sort(function(a, b) {
                            return a[prop] > b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : 0
                        })
                    } 
                    if (first === list[0])
                        list.reverse()
                } else {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    m.redraw.strategy("none");
                }
            }
        }
    }; 

    // text inside the table can be selected with the mouse and will be stored
    // for
    // later retrieval
    obj.getSelected = function(e) {
        // console.log("getSelected");
        var sel = utils.getSelText();
        if(sel.length != 0) {
            vmc.lastSelectedText(utils.getSelText());
            e.stopPropagation();
            // console.log("1000");
        }
        m.redraw.strategy("none");
        // console.log("1001");
    };

    var selectedRow, selectedId;
    var eventHandlerAdded = false;

    // Row callback; reset the previously selected row and select the new one
    obj.selectRow = function (e, row, id) {
        console.log("selectRow " + id);
        unSelectRow();
        selectedRow = row;
        selectedId = id;
        selectedRow.style.background = "#FDFF47";
        if(!eventHandlerAdded) {
            console.log("eventListener added");
            document.addEventListener("click", keyHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener("keypress", keyHandler, false);
            eventHandlerAdded = true;
        }
    };

    var unSelectRow = function () {
        if (selectedRow !== undefined) {
            selectedRow.removeAttribute("style");
            selectedRow = undefined;
            selectedId = undefined;
        }
    };

    var keyHandler = function(e) {
        var num = parseInt(utils.getKeyChar(e), 10);
        if(constants.RATING_NUMS.indexOf(num) != -1) {
            console.log("number typed: " + num);

            // TODO replace with the real table name and the real column name
            // $___{<request>res:/tables/catalogItem</request>}
            model.newValue("item_update_values", selectedId, {"Rating": num}); 
            m.redraw.strategy("diff");
            m.redraw();
        } else if((e.keyCode && (e.keyCode === constants.ESCAPE_KEY))
                || e.type === "click") {
            console.log("eventListener removed");
            document.removeEventListener("click", keyHandler, false);
            document.removeEventListener("keypress", keyHandler, false);
            eventHandlerAdded = false;
            unSelectRow();
        }
    };

    // window seizes for adjusting lists, tables etc
    vm.state = {
        pageY : 0,
        pageHeight : 400
    };
    vm.scrollWatchUpdateStateId = null;

    obj.onScroll = function() {
        return function(e) {
            console.log("scroll event found");
            vm.state.pageY = e.target.scrollTop;
            m.redraw.strategy("none");
            if (!vm.scrollWatchUpdateStateId) {
                vm.scrollWatchUpdateStateId = setTimeout(function() {
                // update pages
                m.redraw();
                vm.scrollWatchUpdateStateId = null;
                }, 50);
            }
        }
    };

    // clean up on unload
    obj.onunload = function() {
        delete vm.state;
        delete vm.scrollWatchUpdateStateId;
    };

    return obj;
};

list.view = function(ctrl) {

    var pageY = ctrl.vm.state.pageY;
    var pageHeight = ctrl.vm.state.pageHeight;
    var begin = pageY / 41 | 0
    // Add 2 so that the top and bottom of the page are filled with
    // next/prev item, not just whitespace if item not in full view
    var end = begin + (pageHeight / 41 | 0 + 2)
    var offset = pageY % 41
    var heightCalc = ctrl.items().length * 41;

    var contextMenuSelection = m("div", {
        id : ctrl.contextMenuId,
        class : "hide"
    }, [
    m(".menu-item.allow-hover", {
        onclick : ctrl.selectAll
    }, "Select all"),
    m(".menu-item.allow-hover", {
        onclick : ctrl.deselectAll
    }, "Deselect all"), 
    m(".menu-item.allow-hover", {
        onclick : ctrl.invertSelection
    }, "Invert selection") ]);

    var header = m("table.listHeader", ctrl.sorts(ctrl.items()), m("tr", [
    m("th.select_col[data-sort-by=selection]", {
         oncontextmenu : ctrl.onContextMenu(ctrl.contextMenuId, "context-menu context-menu-bkg", "hide" )
     }, "S"),
    m("th.name_col[data-sort-by=FileName]", "Name"),
    ${  <request>
            # add other column headers as configured
            <identifier>active:jsPreprocess</identifier>
            <argument name="id">list:table01:header</argument>
        </request>
    } ]), contextMenuSelection);

    var table = m("table", ctrl.items().slice(begin, end).map(function(item, idx) {
        return m("tr", ctrl.initRow(item, idx), {
            key : item.GUID
        },
        [ m("td.select_col", [m("input[type=checkbox]", {
            id : item.GUID,
            checked : ctrl.isSelected(item.GUID),
            onclick : function(e) {ctrl.toggleSelected(this.id);}
        }) ]),
        m("td.nameT_col", {
            onmouseup: function(e) {ctrl.getSelected(e);}
            }, item.FileName), 
        ${  <request>
                # add other columns as configured
                <identifier>active:jsPreprocess</identifier>
                <argument name="id">list:table01:row</argument>
            </request>
         } ])
    }) );

    var table_container = m("div[id=l04]", 
            {style: {position: "relative", top: pageY + "px"}}, table);

    var scrollable = m("div[id=l03]", 
            {style: {height: heightCalc + "px", position: "relative", 
                top: -offset + "px"}}, table_container);

    var scrollable_container = m("div.scrollableContainer[id=l02]", 
            {onscroll: ctrl.onScroll()}, scrollable );

    var list = m("div[id=l01]", [header, scrollable_container]);

    return list;
}
```

Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

There are some good examples of when to change redraw strategy in the docs: http://mithril.js.org/mithril.redraw.html#changing-redraw-strategy

But in general, changing redraw strategy is rarely used if the application state is stored somewhere so Mithril can access and calculate the diff without touching DOM. It seems like your data is elsewhere, so could it be that your `sorts` method is getting expensive to run after a certain size?

You could sort the list only after events that modifies it. Otherwise it will be sorted on every redraw Mithril does, which can be quite often.

`m.start/endComputation` is useful for 3rd party code, especially if it operates on DOM. If the library stores some state, you should use that for the application state as well, so there aren't any redundant and possibly mismatching data.

Comment: I looked at the sort function but it is only called if a click event occurs on the table header. Double checked it by looking into the debugger and commenting out the sort function at all which makes no difference. The data/list for the table is stored in a view-model and it gets sorted there. So I assume the performance lag is the result of the sheer number of items.

Comment: The thing with large numbers of items is that the user rarely benefits from having all of them on screen at once. There's a technique dubbed 'occlusion culling' (don't render what can't be seen) that was [elaborated on in the Mithril blog](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/an-exercise-in-awesomeness.html). I wrote a plugin for using this pattern with components [here](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/f4b4b37e5151a76debdb) — you may be able to adapt this for your own purposes.